# Can I remotely connect my office system "PC-A" to another neighbouring office system "PC-B" through mac address?

Tags: ubuntu, reboot, remote-desktop, mac-address, remote-control

## System description

I have two Ubuntu (Mate-flavour) systems in my office "PC-A" and "PC-B".
previously(4 days ago) I was able to remotely connect both the PC from home.
both are connected with the same office network with there is a slight difference

PC-A directly from the office network port ----> 10.45.xx.58 
PC-B indirectly (with another router from office port 10.45.xx.55) ---> 192.168.0.101

### Other details

Pc-A: is the latest i5 8th generation Desktop with many features included. (I used this system for computational works)

PC-B: an Old i3 desktop with limited features. (used for basic work when PC-A is busy.)

### Problem

Now from home, I am able to connect PC-B through Teamviewer but, PC-A is not connecting.

I don't know the exact reason what happened to the system and I can not go to the office.
Actually, because of the Corona Virus, the Whole country in lockdown for 21 days. so we can't go anywhere.

### Possible solution may work

If some how I am Able to restart the the PC-A, I may able to connect.

### What I Tried

I tried to do ssh to PC-A from PC-B, but it faild (may be my system is disconnected from the lan or may be there is other problem)

### what I want from you

Is it possible to remotely connect PC-A from PC-B through "mac address" and restart the system?
or any other suggestions from your side will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

P.S: I also have another friend ip and username(same configuration as PC-A) but again can not ssh his system because of firewall enabled in his system.

Comment: There's [Wake-On-LAN](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan), but that's usually for turning on a system. "may be my system is disconnected from the lan" ... in that case, not even WoL would help. I doubt anything can.

Comment: Answered as per [title] question. I do suspect an X/Y problem though. A question on 'how do I connect" rather then "how do I connect using method Y"  (esp since method Y will not work in this case, but any other working method probably is the goal where you are after.

Answer (score 0):

No. Not though the MAC address.

The MAC adress is only on the same local network segment. It is no longer relevant once you pass a router.

What might be nice is to look at which routes are set up on that router from *indirectly (with another router*...

But generally speaking, you connect to an IP adress. No to a MAC address. And you either can reach that directly our you go via a gateway. The router is that gateway and it will need to be configured to route data between different networks.

Also possibly complicating this is that these are not the normal range IP adresses but the 10.x.x.x and 192.168.x.x. range which are not guaranteed worldwide uniqued. So if you also use those elsewhere (say same ranger at home and at the office) then you have a potential conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I see no such possibility since your PC-A does not response with ssh (did you try ping also?).

Few thinks:

1. nmap is your best friend in exploring networks. You able to run `nmap 192.168.0.0/24` to make some estimates about new IP address of PC-A for case it has been changed with e.g. DHCP.
2. If you would have some access to PC-A L2 segment, you will be able
   to check ARP records on some host with `arp -n` command for the same IP issue.
3. You can send a magic package to wake up your host for case if it is powered of or sleeping. Therefore for this trick Wake-on-LAN must be enabled on host. There is a [great wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wake-on-LAN#Trigger_a_wake_up) that gives you a point how to. You needs MAC address if you have L2 access and IP address otherwise.

Usually you have L2 coherency when you have an IP address in the same subnet as the target host, and only L3 otherwise (but it is not always so). Routers connects subnetworks on L3. MAC addresses relates to L2.

I also want to note, that commercial use with freeware TeamViewer license is usually blocking. For such case I would advice [DWService](https://www.dwservice.net/) as a TeamViewer alternative. It is robust solution which is open source and free for commercial use.